# JPA property referring to entity underpinned (created) by a complex query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I have a regular JPA entity - First. However, a few properties of that entity refer to other entities (semantically one2one or one2many), e.g. Second. The issue is that Second is not directly backed by a table to refer to. Instead, it is created using a complex native SQL using some data from First, e.g.

(using Spring Data JPA):

First:

```
@Entity
public class First {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "first_pk")
    private Long pk;

    //???
    private Second second;
}

interface FirstRepository extends JpaRepository<First, Long> {}
```

Second:

```
@Entity
public class Second {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "second_id")
    private Integer id;

 ...
}

interface SecondRepository extends JpaRepository<Second, Integer> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "complex SQL select, e.g. using First.pk, but fetching data from multiple (unrelated) tables and, perhaps, even applying some logic, e.g. CASE statements...")
    public Second findSecondUsingFirstPk(Long pk);
}
```

Is there a way in JPA/Hibernate to model such a relationship so that we get the entire fully initialized First entity, e.g. by calling firstEntityRepository.findById

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are using Hibernate, consider using `@Formula` annotation.

Comment: I tried using Formula. It did not work as it typically returns a simple type. When I combined Formula with One2One or Many2One annotations and specified the target type, it produced syntactically incorrect SQL. The same happened as I applied JoinFormula - I either get an incorrect SQL (if I omit OneToMany on Second as the generated SQL wants to have "Second" table which does not exist), or I get

 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.Formula cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Column

if I properly map the Second side, i.e. have OneToMany.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the following:

```
@Entity
public class First {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "first_pk")
    private Long pk;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinFormula("(select pk from ...)")
    private Second second;
}
```

but I generally don't recommend that as the query will be executed every time you fetch a `First` entity. You could workaround this issue by introducing an entity annotated with `@Subselect` like this:

```
@Entity
public class First {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "first_pk")
    private Long pk;

    @ManyToOne
    private SubSecond second;
}

@Entity
@Subselect("(select pk, joinColumn from ...)")
public class SubSecond {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "joinColumn")
    private Long pk;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pk")
    private Second second;
}
```

I don't know what your query does exactly, but I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(First.class)
public interface FirstDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    
    // Not sure what your query should do, but you can also use @MappingCorrelated for more complex needs
    @Mapping("Second[someProperty = VIEW(id) AND ...]")
    SecondDto getSecond();

    @EntityView(Second.class)
    interface SecondDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`FirstDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, FirstDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features